# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable while extracting index and elements are stored in different array in python

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

When i execute the following line

```
u_padded(index)
```

I got the below error:

`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`.

u_padded is a row numpy array having 1 row and 3024 columns.
index is a numpy array having 100 rows and 2016 columns.
What i am trying to do is that the index of each element in u_padded matrix is stored
in index array.In particular if i am trying to extract a element from u_paddedthen index should come from index matrix.
And the resulting matrix should be of the size of index array size i,e; (100,2016).
Plz suggest how to do this.

Thanks,

Manas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> u_padded = np.random.randint(1,100,3024).reshape(1,3024) # random array of 1*3024 elements
>>> u_padded.shape
(1, 3024)
>>> index = np.random.randint(0,3024,100*2016).reshape(100,2016) # random array of 100*2016 indexes with index range = (0,3024)
>>> index.shape
(100, 2016)
>>> u_padded[0,index] # select elements from u_padded with index from index array
array([[91, 53, 67, ..., 55, 13, 66],
       [16, 35, 64, ..., 58, 22, 62],
       [67, 36, 70, ..., 22, 53, 94],
       ..., 
       [28, 49, 61, ..., 89, 74,  8],
       [81, 34, 98, ..., 72, 70, 25],
       [16, 77, 27, ..., 42, 80, 45]])
>>> u_padded[0,index].shape
(100, 3024)
```